# Are references and pointers equal with regards to polymorphism?

Tags: c++, reference, polymorphism

I always think of having to use pointers for polymorphism. Using the canonical example:

```
DrawEngine::render(Shape *shape)
{
    shape->draw();
    shape->visible(true);
}
```

And passing in pointer to various Shape derived classes. Does it work the same with references?

```
DrawEngine::render(Shape &shape)
{
     shape.draw();
     shape.visible(true);
}
```

Is it even valid to do:

```
engine.render(myTriangle); // myTriangle instance of class derived from Shape
```

If this works, are there any differences between the two cases? I tried to find information in Stroustrup, but I found nothing.

I reopened this because I wanted to explore just a tad more.

So at least one difference is dynamic_cast. For me, polymorphism includes the use of dynamic_cast.

Can I go

```
Rhomboid & r = dynamic_cast<Rhomboid &>(shape);
```

What happens if the cast fails? Is this any different?

```
Rhomboid * r = dynamic_cast<Rhomboid*>(&shape);
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

With regard to polymorphism, references work just like pointers.

Comment: @pm100: Directly, sure, but there are different facets. For example, `dynamic_cast` will throw an exception rather than return null on a bad cast.

Comment: @GMan: I think of the `dynamic_cast` example as of basic difference between pointers and references: pointers can legally be NULL, while references cannot. The heart of the question, as I read it, is whether references behave the same with regard to virtual tables. Hence the brief answer.

Comment: The way I see it, references seems to be little more than syntactic sugar on top of pointers.

Comment: @Etienne, that is certainly true for every compiler I have encountered. But I don't get out much.

Comment: @Etienne C++ is just syntactic sugar on top of machine code :-).

Answer (score 10):

Regarding `dynamic_cast`, a failed cast produces a nullpointer with pointers, and results in a throw of a `bad_cast` (IIRC) exception with references.

One reason is that there's no such thing as a valid null-reference.

And possibly another reason (but it could just be an unintentionally useful emergent feature) is that sometimes one needs the exception and sometimes one needs the easy-to-check nullpointer, and no matter whether you have a reference or pointer at hand it takes at most a dereferencing or address operator to obtain the behavior you want.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score -1):

Pointers help in other ways as well. Like passing a string and accepting it as char* parameter in a function.

Consider the old example of reversing a string in place:

```
void reversestring(char* myString)
{
int firstPos=0;
int lastPos=myString.length - 1;
while (firstPos < lastPos)
{
  char temp=myString[firstPos];
  myString[firstPos]=myString[lastPos];
  myString[lastPos]=temp;
  firstPos++;
  lastPos--;
}
}
```

Writing code for string manipulation like these using references won't be that simple.

Comment: myString.length? Is that c++?

Comment: @TheLightSpark It would be valid if `myString` was a `std::string`, but I do believe it's invalid for a raw C string.  Also, `length` should be a function call, but that's nitpicking.

Comment: If it's a std::string it CAN be a reference. In modern C++ you can use std::array instead of a char*, or better yet use std::string