# polymorphic C++ references

Tags: c++, polymorphism, reference

I was wondering **how** you can do polymorphism with references, as opposed to pointers.

To clarify, see the following minimal example:

```
class A;

class B {
  public:
    A& a; ///////////////// <- #1
    B();
    void doStuff();
};

class A {
  public:
    virtual void doSmth() = 0;
};
void B::doStuff() {
  a.doSmth();
}

class A1 : public A {
  public:
    void doSmth() {
    }
};

B::B() : a(
    *        ////////////// <- #2
      (new A1)  /////////// <- #3
     ) {
}
```

This compiles and works, but as the most important point here is that `a` in line `#1` is a reference, so in order to be able to use it polymorphically (is that an actual word?), as shown in line `#3` I have to "convert a pointer to a reference" by dereferencing it.

This strikes me as a bit odd, and I was wondering if there is a better (in the sense of *cleaner*) way. Is it just me?

#### Rationale

It would be great if I didn't need a `new` at all, but when declaring (!) `B` I have no clue how to create an instance of `A1` (!) as `A` is a forward declaration -- `A1` is implemented in the same compilation unit as `B`. Still, is there a real need for dynamic memory allocation in this case? How would you do this?

Sorry for the slightly twofold question.

### Edit

Note: `B` is huge (and I cannot make a template class of it), and will go out of scope precisely when the program terminates -- `a` is small and makes two big modules talk to each other, it will be needed as long as the instance of `B` lives (there is only one).

### Edit 2

I just realised, that since both `A` and `B` are effectively singletons, I can simply create a `static` instance of `A1` in the compilation unit of `B`, avoiding dynamic memory allocation (even if there were two `B`s they could easily use the same instance of `A`). To be fair, I did not post this as answer, but will accept the answer that prompted me to come up with this *solution*.

Comment: Why not just fix things so that the definition of `A1` appears *before* the definition of `B`?

Comment: if B allways uses an A1 then why do you not just declare an object of type A1 instead of a reference to an A?

Comment: @Oli: to reduce dependencies?

Comment: @Simon: I'd prefer to deal with dependencies than deal with references to dynamically-created objects!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Normally, I'd say you are right, but this whole thing is actually (as Simon guessed) to reduce dependencies. See *Edit*, please.

Comment: @bitmask: I don't see what the edit has to do with dependencies.  Without any further information, the correct answer (in terms of best practice) is currently to just rearrange your definitions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are references and pointers equal with regards to polymorphism?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835741/are-references-and-pointers-equal-with-regards-to-polymorphism)

Comment: Cannot help but saying it: this code LEAKS MEMORY. You have no not hackish way to free what a is pointing to.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There's nothing odd. Polymorphisms works both for pointers *and* references:

```
struct Base { };
struct Derived : Base;

void foo(Base &);

int main() {
  Derived x;
  foo(x);    // fine
}
```

You're conflating this with another issue, namely creating a reference to a dynamic object:

```
T * pt = new T;
T & rt = *pt;

T & x = *new T;  // same effect
```

Note that it's generally very bad style to track a dynamic object *only* by reference, because the only way to delete it is via `delete &x;`, and it's very hard to see that `x` needs cleaning up.

There are two immediate alternatives for your design: 1) make `a` a member object in `B`, or 2) make `a` a `shared_ptr<A>` or `unique_ptr<A>` and change the initalizer to `a(new A1)`. It all depends on whether you actually need the polymorphic behaviour, i.e. if you have other constructors for `B` which assign a different derived class to `a` other than `A1`.

Comment: Well, the simplest thing would be to have `A* const a` instead of `A& a`, but that is worse, as an non-reseatable pointer is represented better by a reference, isn't it? To solution 2): dependencies ...

Comment: Bear in mind that any sort of resource-holding members will give your class much more complicated copy and assignment semantics. You have to decide if that's worth it. Dependencies might be mitigated by suitable forward-declarations, but only if you go for the pointer solution (but you might be able to avoid the virtual dispatch).

Comment: `B` is effectively a singleton, `A` too. Does this make "tracking a dynamic object *only* by reference" less of a bad practice?

Comment: No. In that case use a `unique_ptr`, that's by far the cleanest PIMPL solution. Your class will not be copyable, but that should be OK then.

Comment: "an non-reseatable pointer is represented better by a reference, isn't it?" of course not. why would any pointer ever be best represented by a reference? it's not a reference: it's a pointer. specifically, a bog-standard `const` pointer. please just use a `*const`, if only so that anyone reading your code (including future you) can make useful guesses on semantics.

Answer (score 3):

> Still, is there a real need for dynamic memory allocation in this
>   case?

No. Just define A1 first and then make it a normal member of B.

Polymorphism works just fine with both references and pointers.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a bit odd.  If you want a member-variable of type `A1` (rather than a reference), why not just rearrange your code so that the definition of `A1` appears before the definition of `B`?

Answer (score 1):

Erm, is this not sufficient?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A;

struct B
{
  B(A& a);

  void foo();

  A& _a;
};

struct A
{
  virtual void foo() =0;
};

struct A1 : public A
{
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "A1::foo" << std::endl; }
};

B::B(A& a) : _a(a) {}
void B::foo() { _a.foo(); }


int main(void)
{ 
  A1 a;  // instance of A1
  B b(a); // construct B with it

  b.foo();
}
```

Comment: Nope, the guy who creates `B` has less of a clue how to create a `A1` instance. And it doesn't solve the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

> Still, is there a real need for dynamic memory allocation in this case?

Either the dynamic memory allocation or injecting the reference into B's ctor.

Answer (score 0):

It's no stretch to imagine why references can work polymorphically like pointers (not to mention references are often implemented as pointers anyway). Here's a quick example:

```
class Base { 
public:
    virtual void something() { }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void something() { }
};

Base& foo() {
    static Derived d;
    return d;
}

foo().something(); // calls Derived's something
```

Also why are you allocating dynamic memory for a reference? You probably shouldn't be using a reference in this case at all. Also, writing classes with reference members effectively prevents assignment (as I heard someone say quite well).

Answer (score -1):

I realize this is a really old post but there is another option you have for handling references for dynamically allocated objects. You can assign a reference to the dynamically allocated object. Below is some dummy code to give you an idea of how this works.

```
struct A
{
  int b;
  virtual void print();
  A(int val):b(val) {}
};

struct A_child:public A
{
  A_child(int val):A(val) {}
  void print();
};

void A:print()
{
cout<<"parent\n";
}

void A_child:print()
{
cout<<"child\n";
}

struct test_ref
{
A *& ref;
test_ref(A * ptr) : ref(ptr)
}

int main()
{

  test_ref parent(new A(12));
  parent.ref->print();

  test_ref child(new A_child(15));
  child.ref->print();
}
```

To be honest I am not certain when this is a good idea. I just wanted to show an alternative approach where you dont have to dereference the dynamically allocated memory when initializing an object.

I am also pretty certain dynamically allocating a pointer while initializing a class where the pointer is stored as a reference pointer will probably lead to a memory leak unless you can delete the reference pointer.

Comment: This is a totally dumb and wrong thing. You are taking a reference to a function-local variable and storing it past the scope of the function. This could never work.