# reference instead of pointer to abstract class

Tags: c++, oop, class, object, abstract-class

I'm curious if in the following program `Base* base` in class `Container` can be replaced with `Base& base`?
With `Base base` it can't be replaced, because `Base` is abstract.
With `Base& base` the object should be allocated somewhere, so I still would not be able to get rid of the pointer to the allocated object.

```
#include <iostream>
class Base
{   public:
    virtual void str()=0;
};

class A : public Base
{   int i;
    public:
    A(int i):i(i){}
    void str(){std::cout<<i<<std::endl;}
};

class B : public Base
{   double f;
    public:
    B(double f):f(f){}
    void str(){std::cout<<f<<std::endl;}
};

class Container
{   Base *base;
    public:
    Container(int i)   { base=new A(i);}
    Container(double f) { base=new B(f);}
    void str(){ base->str();}
};
int main ()
{   
    Container c1(8),c2(13.0);  
    c1.str();   
    c2.str();  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: I think this post should give you an answer : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192069/polymorphic-c-references

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your code, I would't recommend it, because `Container` is the owner of `base` and a reference, *semantically*, means something else (an alias).

Technically, there's nothing stopping you:

```
class Container
{   Base &base;
    public:
    Container(int i) : base(*new A(i))   {}
    Container(double f) : base(*new B(f)) {}
    void str(){ base->str();}
};
```

Note that references have to be initialized in the initializer list.

You'd still need to clean up the memory, and it would look ugly with a reference:

```
~Container() { delete &base; }
```

instead of

```
~Container() { delete base; }
```

if you used pointers. Of course, using a `std::unique_ptr` instead of either of these two would make life **a whole lot easier**.

Also, be sure to implement (or declare as `private` or `deleted`) the copy constructor or assignment operator.

*Later spot* - You **need** to provide `Base` with a `virtual` destructor, otherwise you'll run into undefined behavior territory when you'll attempt to clean up the memory.