# C++ virtual method confusion

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods, virtual

I have a basic C++ question about inheritance and virtual methods.

Please regard this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  virtual void f() {cout << "A\n";};
};

class B : public A {
public:
  void f() {cout << "B\n";};
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B b;
  vector<A> v;
  v.push_back(a);
  v.push_back(b);

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    v.at(i).f();
}
```

If I execute this code, it prints out

```
A
A
```

I do not understand why it does not print

```
A
B
```

because the "f" method is declared as virtual.
I would like to know why the program behaves in this way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read about [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your vector contains `A` objects:

```
vector<A> v;
```

when you push_back a `B` object into it, the vector copies the `A` part of it into a new `A` object.  It is the equivalent of doing this:

```
A a;
B b;
a = b;
a.f();
```

This is called [*object slicing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: Ah, I see. I find this behavior very confusing, maybe because I'm coming from the Java world ...

Comment: @SvenHager right, that's value semantics for you. In Java "objects" are a kind of pointer/reference, and the equivalent of the vector would hold these references, so there is scope for dynamic dispatch. In C++, you would store smart pointers to the base class to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3):

You are [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) the object, you need to use pointers or [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192069/polymorphic-c-references) for this to behave properly. Example using pointers:

```
int main()
{
  vector<A*> v;
  v.push_back(new A);
  v.push_back(new B );

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    v[i]->f();
}
```

This will give you the `polymorphic` behavior you wanted and will have this output:

```
A
B
```

Answer (score 2):

`b` is sliced to an instance of `A` when it's copied for insertion into the `vector`, you would have to use `vector<A*>` for this to work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You should have vector of pointers in order to have polymorphic behavior :)

Comment: you can use std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> a;

Comment: As AnatolyS you could user shared pointers to avoid the hassle of getting rid of the objects (only in the case of dynamic allocation !) or you can use raw/"classic" pointers , but make sure using the array only when the pointers are pointed to _valid_ objects (e.g. not after stack unwinding)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, only pointers and references to objects behave polymorphically. Your vector contains non polymorphic objects of type A.

try

```
int main() {
  A a;
  B b;
  vector<A*> v;
  v.push_back(&a);
  v.push_back(&b);

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    v.at(i)->f();
```

Though you need to be aware that those pointers will become invalid when a and b are destroyed (when they go out of scope).

Answer (score 0):

The vector v contains Objects for Type A. When you push back objects to v these objects are instantiated using the copy constructor of A. Like that each of the objects you call later on the function f for is actually of type A and will never execute B's f().