# Casting a variable passed by reference in C++

Tags: c++

I have some code that passes a variable by reference, but doesn't result in the variable being updated in the calling code as I would expect;

```
// Interface classes
class Animal{};

class Car{
public:
    virtual void testDrive(Animal &animal) = 0;
};


// A specific implementation
class Bear : public Animal{
public:
    int testthing = 0;
};

void Ferrari::testDrive(Animal &animal){
    Bear b = dynamic_cast<Bear &>(animal);

    b.testthing = 1;
}


// Use those classes, doesn't need to know about Bear or Ferrari
int main()
{
    // Set up myCar and myAnimal

    myCar.testDrive(myAnimal)  // ** but myAnimal is unchanged! **
}
```

I've actually been able to get this to work (`myAnimal` is updated with `testthing = 1`) by passing a pointer instead, but I'd be interested to know what's going on here.

As I understand it passing a variable by reference is very closely related to passing a pointer anyway, and "With regard to polymorphism, references work just like pointers"*.

So why does one work and the other not? Is there a simple way to get this to work with a reference?

*[Are references and pointers equal with regards to polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835741/are-references-and-pointers-equal-with-regards-to-polymorphism)

EDIT: this is just an example to show my meaning, obviously not production code.

Comment: P.S.: apologies for the mixed metaphor of bears driving cars ;)

Comment: `Bear b = dynamic_cast<Bear &>(animal);` makes a copy. You probably want `Bear& b = dynamic_cast<Bear &>(animal);`

Comment: Ok, thanks. The same doesn't seem to happen with a pointer, can you explain why, and whether there's a way to get this working with a reference?

Comment: Whoever downvoted btw, could I ask why? If there's a problem with the question I'd like to avoid it in future.

Comment: I guess that missing semicolons + missing declarations for `myCar` and `myAnimal` = downvote (though I can only guess, it wasn't me)

Comment: Ah. Well, it's just an example, I've simplified from the real code and added a comment for the declarations. But I'll try to remember the semicolons next time. (ok cheers, who knows really!)

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question. Indeed, it's really a simple typo, but it's well-posed. Could do with some `;` after class declarations though.

Comment: Thanks Bathsheba, I appreciate that. I do always spend quite a bit of time trying to get the question as clear as possible, so it's a little frustrating to see downvotes with no explanation. I've added semicolons though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Bear b = dynamic_cast<Bear &>(animal);` is taking a value copy of the cast value of `animal`, so modifications on `b` will not affect the original.

You want `Bear& b = dynamic_cast<Bear &>(animal);` instead. Then `b` is itself a reference.

Note that if `dynamic_cast` fails when taking a reference cast, then `std::bad_cast` is thrown. You ought to deal with that appropriately.

Comment: Ok, thanks! And thanks for the note on bad_cast. So that only applies for the reference cast, for a pointer you could check for null using `if (b) { doSomeStuff() }`, right? (from http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php)

Comment: Indeed. A `dynamic_cast` has failed on a pointer cast if the resulting pointer compares `true` against `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what the question is. Normal casting works ok:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// Interface classes
class Animal{};

class Car{
public:
    virtual void testDrive(Animal &animal) = 0;
};

class Ferrari : public Car {
public:
    void testDrive(Animal &animal);
};


// A specific implementation
class Bear : public Animal{
public:
    int testthing = 0;
};


    void Ferrari::testDrive(Animal &animal){
        Bear & b = (Bear &) animal;

        b.testthing = 1;
    }


// Use those classes, doesn't need to know about Bear or Ferrari
int main()
{
// Set up myCar and myAnimal
    Animal myAnimal;
    Ferrari myCar ;
myCar.testDrive(myAnimal);  // ** but myAnimal is unchanged! **
cout << ((Bear &)myAnimal).testthing ;

}
```

Prints:
1

Comment: As Bathsheba pointed out, I was taking a copy during the cast - I didn't realise that to cast a reference you need to explicitly define the variable as a reference, hence `Bear & b` rather than `Bear b`. Thanks.